# Apple Developer Account 100 devices limit is over?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Kindly let me know what are the best options if 100 devices limit is over in Apple Developer account and we need to add more UDIDs?

Comment: Look into testflight

Comment: Remove old unused device UDIDs, this the only way to do it if you want to test it internally, however you should always use TestFlight to distribute apps, it doesn't required UDID, so it will keep the limit in control.

Comment: Hello, do you know if it is really over? It seems it is only allowed 3 devices per account

Answer (score 5):

The limit is 100 devices per device type, which means that you can register 100 iPhones, 100 iPads, 100 Apple TVs and 100 Apple Watches to your developer account. Assuming that registering devices using UDIDs is for development purposes, these numbers are pretty enough. You can send test builds using Testflight which allows for external testing up to 1000 users with up to 10 devices each. Note that external testing requires a beta review for the first build of each version of your app.

If you hit the limit of 100 iPhones in your account, you can delete the UDIDs you do not use and free space when your account renewal time comes.

Comment: Deleting UDIDs won't help right now because 6months are remaining for renewal period.Testflight is nice solution as of now but also I am thinking to take another developer account because client is not too much technical.

Comment: Testflight is much easier for sending test builds that custom udid based solutions.